# Number of Vertices of Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, definition, cardinals, topological-graph-theory

So, I was looking at some graph theoretical stuff, more specifically Topological Graph Theory, and I had a question about the definition of graphs:  is there usually a condition in the definition limiting the number of vertices?  Perhaps that the set of Vertices is countable? or even finite?  If not, is such a condition commonly put on the set of edges?  I was thinking about this, and I believe if there is no condition you can get graphs which act MUCH differently than finite graphs. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Graphs are discrete structures. i don't see any "uncountable" nodes in a graph. the number of edges is bounded by the number of vertices unless you are dealing with hypergraphs. A graph is a modeling structure-- and a very powerful one. Whichever applies to your problem.

Comment: @ashley: this is not true. An $n$-vertex graph, even one with no loops or multiple edges, can have ${n \choose 2}$ edges.

Comment: you must be referring to "...by the number of vertices" which is that the number of vertices determines $|E|$. thats nothing but trivial.

Comment: @ashley: when people say "$A$ is bounded by $B$" I generally take that to mean "$A \le B$" which is not true in this case. Perhaps you mean "$A$ is controlled by $B$" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some parts of graph theory people probably typically restrict their attention to finite graphs. In other parts there's no reason to do this. For example, [Ramsey theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory) frequently deals with infinite graphs. It's also natural to use countable [Cayley graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) in [geometric group theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_group_theory).

The [Rado graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph) is a specific example of an interesting infinite graph.

Answer (score 2):

In full generality, if $S$ is a set, then we can define graphs with the vertex set $S$ (such as the complete graph).  Many important mathematical objects can be rephrased as graphs (functions, relations, etc.), so you've probably encountered graphs with an uncountable number of vertices this way.

A famous graph theory problem where an uncountable number of vertices arises is the [chromatic number of the plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem):

> In geometric graph theory, the Hadwiger–Nelson problem, named after
>   Hugo Hadwiger and Edward Nelson, asks for the minimum number of colors
>   required to color the plane such that no two points at distance 1 from
>   each other have the same color. The answer is unknown, but has been
>   narrowed down to one of the numbers 4, 5, 6 or 7. **The correct value
>   may actually depend on the choice of axioms for set theory** (Shelah &
>   Soifer 2003).

[emphasis mine]

We see that properties of graphs with an uncountable number of vertices may have behaviour different from graphs with a finite or countable number of vertices.  Whether or not you want to work with such graphs is more of a matter of personal taste, than of any inherent barrier in graph theory.